# SSIS Script Task Destination Component Not Completing

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I have an SSIS Data Flow that uses a script task to create a row, process the row, and then write the result of one of the columns to a variable in a destination script task.

Destination Script is simply:

```
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        '
        Variables.CampaignId = Row.CampaignId
        '
    End Sub
```

[DataFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sprMo.png)

Is there something I am missing here? Do I need to be calling the end of the component? or testing for the end of the rowset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadWriteVariables need to be written to in PostExecute and cannot be written to in the RowBuffer.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute> _
<CLSCompliant(False)> _
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Dim CampID As String

    ' This method is called after all the rows have passed through this component.

    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
        MyBase.PostExecute()

        Variables.CampaignId = CampID

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        CampID = Row.CampaignId

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answered my own question, but hopefully this helps someone else whom the error code does not generate for them. After multiple runs I finally got an error code about readwrite variable outside of post execute which helped tremendously with troubleshooting. Gotta love Microsoft...